# Multiple unique random values in a single request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to make an HTTP request in JMeter that contains multiple random numbers within a fixed range (specifically 0-50). With each request, I need to send out about 45 different integers, so on any given request, there are six integers within said range that are not included. Obviously {__Random()} doesn't work, as it will inevitably generate some equal values. My idea, and please bear with me because I am very new to this, was to create an array with the integers, such as:

`String line = "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.....";
 String[] numbers = line.split(",");`

and then assign them fixed variable names to include in the request. I can do this with counter with CSV data, but I'm unsure about how to do this with an array.

`vars.put("VAR_" + counter, line);
 VAR_1 = 1
 VAR_2 = 2
   and so on...`

then shuffle the array (which I do not know how to do in Beanshell) and generate something like:

`VAR_1 = 16
 VAR_2 = 27
   ...`

to send with the next request.

If anyone could help me with this, or suggest a simpler way, I would great appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's kind of ugly and cumbersome, but fairly simple and does exactly what I needed it to do. In JSR223 PreProcessor, my code is

```
def list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,.....];
Collections.shuffle(list);
String VAR_1 = Integer.toString(list.getAt(0));
vars.put("VAR_1", VAR_1);
String VAR_2 = Integer.toString(list.getAt(1));
vars.put("VAR_2", VAR_2);
String VAR_3 = Integer.toString(list.getAt(2));
and so on.....
```

I had to input the 50 variables manually. I'm sure there was a simpler way, but I'm quite satisfied. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. To shuffle the list just use [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method
2. Consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell as it is:

   - More Java compliant
   - Has better performance
   - Has built-in support of JSON, XML and some "syntax sugar" which minimises and simplifies code

   Check out [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I switched over to JSR223 + Groovy, but I'm still having trouble. I saw a comment that you made in response to someone doing something similar, and you suggested using a Secure.Random class. I tried something like this `Random rand = new SecureRandom()
int number = rand.nextInt(50);` but it did not work. Again, I'm trying to generate about 45 unique integers out of 50 for any given request.

Comment: Why don't you just use [Counter test element or __counter()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) function and get sequential numbers? 45 random numbers out of 50 doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I know it sounds odd, but it's what I need to do. It's a relatively simple concept; on any given request there will be 5 integers that are not included from the range. I am testing a game that relies on choosing numbers. This solution would work quite well, if only I could shuffle the numbers after every request. 'BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.csv"));
String line;
int counter = 1;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   vars.put("VAR_" + counter, line);
   counter++;
}
br.close();'